# Stack navigator header disappear and can't use navigation.navigate(

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have this navigation structure:

```
const TabNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name='dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
            <Tab.Screen name='info' component={Info} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator>
                        <Stack.Screen name='main' component={TabNavigator} />
                        <Stack.Screen name='market' component={Market} />
                        <Stack.Screen name='cart' component={Cart} />
                        <Stack.Screen name='ongoingdelivery' component={OngoingDelivery} />
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </Provider>
        </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
};
```

the first screen shown is "Dashboard" whose live inside the "TabNavigator". After that, inside "Market" component, on a button, I use  `props.navigation.navigate('market')` and I successfully navigate to market, inside Market component, I navigate to "Cart" the same way. So when I am on "Cart" screen, I try to use `props.navigation.navigate('ongoingdelivery')` and nothing happens. Not even an error is thrown. But if I instead of "ongoingdelivery" I navigate back to market, it works. why?